# Height not the same on prepend input when type is text/password

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got a problem in bootstrap prepend, when i put input="text" render is not the same with input="password"

Screen :

[image]

Does anyone has an idea what's happend ?

```
<label for="login" class="sr-only">Login :</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" value="test" class="form-control" placeholder="Login" pattern=".{4,}" required title="Login" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" autofocus>
</div>
<label for="password" class="sr-only">Mot de passe :</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
  </div>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" aria-label="Mot de passe"  pattern=".{4,}" required title="Mot de passe" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
</div>
```

Thank You for your help

Comment: I don't see any problem in my local machine, please see your custom CSS, that conflict your UI

Comment: You are using the same `id` for both span elements. This may cause issues as it is invalid HTML.

Comment: I've try to change the span id with no change.

Comment: OK it was my custom CSS. @NishargShah Thank you for your help